# Word userform only shows with the last item found

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform

I want to find certain errors in a document and handle them individually with a modeless userform. With the following code the userform only shows at the last error found instead of showing at each error as I intended. I set it modeless since the user would need to move around and do various things. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

1. This is the code in the main module.

   ```
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim doc As Document
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set rng = doc.Range.Duplicate    
    With rng.Find
      .text = "error"
      Do While rng.Find.Execute
          rng.Select
          UserForm1.Show vbModeless
      Loop
    End With
   ```
2. This is the code in the form, which contains primarily a command button.

   ```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
      Action1
    Else
      Action2
      unload Me
    End If
    End Sub
   ```

I tried to add "DoEvents" after userform1.show in the above code, hoping the form can remain open, but it simply moved on and the form dissapearred with a blink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the form is not opened in a modal, the program will continue to run and you must give control of this procedure to the form after it is opened instead of leaving it in this procedure.
In order to transfer the control of program execution to the form, it is necessary to dispose of the form during its initialization or activation.

```vb
Option Explicit


Public Rng_Word_userform_only_shows_with_the_last_item_found As Range

Rem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76586384/word-userform-only-shows-with-the-last-item-found
Sub Word_userform_only_shows_with_the_last_item_found()
 Dim rng As Range
 Dim doc As Document
 Set doc = ActiveDocument
 If Not Rng_Word_userform_only_shows_with_the_last_item_found Is Nothing Then
    Set rng = Rng_Word_userform_only_shows_with_the_last_item_found
 Else
    Set rng = doc.Range.Duplicate
 End If
 With rng.Find
   .Text = "error"
   Do
        If rng.Find.Execute() Then
            rng.Select
            rng.Document.ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView rng
       
            Rem When the form is not opened in a modal, the program will continue to run _
                      and you must give control of this procedure to the form after it is opened instead of leaving it in this procedure
            Rem In order to transfer the control of program execution to the form, _
                 it is necessary to dispose of the form during its initialization or activation.
            With UserForm1
                .Show vbModeless
                Set .rng = rng
                Exit Sub
            End With
        Else
            Set Rng_Word_userform_only_shows_with_the_last_item_found = Nothing
            Exit Do
            
        End If
   Loop
 End With
End Sub
```

[image]

- **This is the code in the form**:

```vb
Option Explicit
Private is_loaded As Boolean 'just for test
Public rng As Range

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
'   Action1
 Else
'   Action2
   rng.SetRange rng.End, rng.End ' rng.Document.Range.End
   Set Module1.Rng_Word_userform_only_shows_with_the_last_item_found = rng
   Unload Me
   Module1.Word_userform_only_shows_with_the_last_item_found
 End If
End Sub

'just for test
Public Property Get Isloaded() As Variant
    Isloaded = is_loaded
End Property
'just for test
Public Property Let Isloaded(ByVal vNewValue As Variant)
    is_loaded = vNewValue
End Property
'just for test
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    is_loaded = True
End Sub
'just for test
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    Isloaded = False
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is brilliant-- I never thought we can use "exit sub" to pass control over to the form! I once thought with default instance one could never use the form more than once during the run, but "exit sub" paired with re-executing the sub apparently did the trick! 
I did try to simplify by omitting setting two ranges. For the simple test it seems to work, so want to check your thought on this. Also, if this code is a portion of a much larger sub, would you delegate this part to a sub and calling it from elsewhere?

Comment: @CNYang I am not very clear about your needs, I am just answering this question for *"only shows with the last item found"* you asked, after all, it is not my needs. If you have further needs, you may want to open a separate post and then ask everyone. As long as the code can be improved in a streamlined and effective way, it is worth a try. I think too. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time and getting back to me promptly with the creative answer!